# How to measure residual charge in capacitor?

Tags: electricity, electrons, electric-current, charge, capacitance

I understand how to measure capacitance of capacitor with multimeter but it is possible to measure residual charge of "half-discharged" capacitor?

Comment: Yes, you need a ballistic galvanometer

Comment: so it is impossible to measure with digital multimeter?

Comment: Check the answer below

Comment: You are much better off using a coulomb meter DIY http://www.dicks-website.eu/coulombmeter/enindex.htm or purchased complete. What value of capacitance are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to measure the voltage across a discharging capacitor by a normal voltmeter because the capacitor discharges within a fraction of a second (the depending upon the capacity is never larger than a few seconds). The voltmeter coil wouldn't be able to rotate when there is such a quick discharge (and you need V to find Q ). Under such a condition a ballistic galvanometer is used which is built for the purpose of studying quick discharges ( its coil is made such). When such a quick discharge passes through the Ballistic Galvanometer there is a whole experiment to measure its capacity and then charge. I did this experiment and it's not possible without a B.G.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What's the difference between ballistic galvanometer and classic galvanometer?

Comment: @trenccan There is a whole lot of difference. B.G oscillates(generally )...Its in the material of the coil . You will have to see the differential eqn of B.G